# Windows 10 Apache Cordova app with barcode error on build

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, windows-10, barcode-scanner

On build a app (clean, without any plugin or extra code) with only barcodescanner the VS2015 crash this errors:

[image]

Only Windows 10. In 8.1 cordova app or Android app, all clear.

Comment: the barcode scanner used it's [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner)

Comment: It seems the CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj is missing.Try clear the cordova cache by tools->Tools for Apache Cordova->Clear Cordova Cache.

Comment: Yeah..but CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj file exists in the folder. I've cleared cordova cache but same error...too change project folder and change Cordova CLI version (from 6.1.1 to 5.1.1) and the same issue

Comment: Have you tried creating a totally new project?

Comment: Yes...but the error persist...It would be a bug in version 6.1.1 Cordova CLI with Windows 10? The same project compiling for Windows 8.1 or Android does not display any errors.